Why are columns not in my SELECT coming in the output when looking at the execution plan?
I am running the below query and the below index is present to satisfy the query.
SELECT top 100 RCLNT, RBUKRS, RYEAR, RACCT, DRCRK, SUM(ISNULL([000],0.00)) AS CSLVT,SUM(ISNULL([001],0.00)) AS CSL01,SUM(ISNULL([002],0.00)) AS CSL02,SUM(ISNULL([003],0.00)) AS CSL03,SUM(ISNULL([004],0.00)) AS CSL04,SUM(ISNULL([005],0.00)) AS CSL05,SUM(ISNULL([006],0.00)) AS CSL06,SUM(ISNULL([007],0.00)) AS CSL07,SUM(ISNULL([008],0.00)) AS CSL08,SUM(ISNULL([009],0.00)) AS CSL09,SUM(ISNULL([010],0.00)) AS CSL10,SUM(ISNULL([011],0.00)) AS CSL11,SUM(ISNULL([012],0.00)) AS CSL12,SUM(ISNULL([013],0.00)) AS CSL13,SUM(ISNULL([014],0.00)) AS CSL14,SUM(ISNULL([015],0.00)) AS CSL15,SUM(ISNULL([016],0.00)) AS CSL16
FROM dbo.ACDOCA WITH (NOLOCK)

PIVOT
(
MAX(ACDOCA.CSL) FOR ACDOCA.POPER IN ([000],[001],[002],[003],[004],[005],[006],[007],[008],[009],[010],[011],[012],[013],[014],[015],[016])
) AS ACDOC_PIV
GROUP BY RCLNT, RBUKRS, RYEAR, RACCT, DRCRK

Index:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ACDOCA_RCLNT_RBUKRS_RYEAR_RACCT_DRCRK_INCL_CSL_POPER] ON [dbo].[ACDOCA]
(
    [RCLNT] ASC,
    [RBUKRS] ASC,
    [RYEAR] ASC,
    [RACCT] ASC,
    [DRCRK] ASC
)
INCLUDE([CSL],[POPER]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

But, for some reason SQL Server is doing a Clustered Key lookup to fetch all the other columns in the table. Is there any reason why it's doing that and can it be avoided to improve performance?
Execution plan screenshot:


In aggregation queries which include most records in the table, there may not be much of a difference between scanning the clustered index and scanning a non clustered index...because most rows are involved in the aggregation.

Can you see which columns are being looked up from the PK? Perhaps it's not using IX_ACDOCA_RCLNT_RBUKRS_RYEAR_RACCT_DRCRK_INCL_CSL_POPER but some other index?

Off main topic but TOP 100 with no ORDER BY and NOLOCK both are dubious

@MartinSmith Thanks, your answered worked! I added TOP 100 because the table contains a billion rows and NOLOCK because the table is not going to be updated.

As Itzik Ben Gan explains here

The design of the PIVOT operator requires you to explicitly specify
the aggregation and spreading elements, but lets SQL Server implicitly
figure out the grouping element by elimination. Whichever [remaining] columns appear in the source table that is provided as the input to the PIVOT
operator, they implicitly become the grouping element.

If you use a table expression that only projects the relevant columns and PIVOT that instead you avoid the issue with unwanted/unexpected columns participating in the implicit GROUP BY. You should also get rid of the explicit GROUP BY and the SUM as then the implicit GROUP BY columns will be the same as your explicit grouping anyway so this was only needed due to the presence of those columns adding additional unwanted groups.
So you can use (Fiddle)
WITH PivotSource
     AS (SELECT RCLNT,
                RBUKRS,
                RYEAR,
                RACCT,
                DRCRK,
                CSL,
                POPER
         FROM   ACDOCA)
SELECT TOP 100 RCLNT,
               RBUKRS,
               RYEAR,
               RACCT,
               DRCRK,
               ISNULL([000], 0.00) AS CSLVT,
               ISNULL([001], 0.00) AS CSL01,
               ISNULL([002], 0.00) AS CSL02,
               ISNULL([003], 0.00) AS CSL03,
               ISNULL([004], 0.00) AS CSL04,
               ISNULL([005], 0.00) AS CSL05,
               ISNULL([006], 0.00) AS CSL06,
               ISNULL([007], 0.00) AS CSL07,
               ISNULL([008], 0.00) AS CSL08,
               ISNULL([009], 0.00) AS CSL09,
               ISNULL([010], 0.00) AS CSL10,
               ISNULL([011], 0.00) AS CSL11,
               ISNULL([012], 0.00) AS CSL12,
               ISNULL([013], 0.00) AS CSL13,
               ISNULL([014], 0.00) AS CSL14,
               ISNULL([015], 0.00) AS CSL15,
               ISNULL([016], 0.00) AS CSL16
FROM   PivotSource
PIVOT ( MAX(CSL)
      FOR POPER IN ([000],[001],[002],[003],[004],[005],[006],[007],[008],[009],[010],[011],[012],[013],[014],[015],[016]) ) AS ACDOC_PIV
--ORDER BY /*Todo: TOP 100 ordered by what?*/

